Angular how to unit test Firebase (v19)
In my Angular application I wrapped the connection to the store in a service but I can't test it.
In the main documentation is written:
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  getItemsCollection() {
    const itemCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items');
    return collectionData<Item>(itemCollection);
  }

  getItemsCollection(id: string) {
    const itemDocument = doc(this.firestore, 'items' + id);
    return docData<Item>(itemDocument);
  }

but how can i test it?
I'm expecting to provide "Firestore" using a spy object or something mocked but how can i do it that could work also for other document/collection action (as update/add/delete)
